Cannot request a token to retrieve MS OneDrive files
In the past, I was able to request a bearer token by sending a request to https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token with the client id, client secret, tenant id, scope, username, and password. But with 2FA being a requirement, it's now broken.
I am trying obtain the token using msal python Confidential App and  Device Flow and but I am getting some permission issues.
App Permissions
I've tried msal.ConfidentialClientApplication to obtain the token but it's asking for Delegated Authentication Flow authentication.
import os
import requests

import msal

client_id = os.getenv("client_id")
client_secret = os.getenv("client_secret")
tenant_id = os.getenv("tenant_id")
scopes = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]


app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
        client_id,
        authority=f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}",
        client_credential=client_secret,
    )

def get_ms_token():
    result = app.acquire_token_silent(scopes=scopes, account=None)
    if not result:
        result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scopes)
    
    if "access_token" in result:
        return result["access_token"]
    raise Exception("ms token error")

headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {get_ms_token()}"}
resp = requests.get("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children", headers=headers)
if resp.status_code != 200:
    print(resp.text)

resp {"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"/me request is only valid with delegated authentication flow.","innerError":{"date":"2024-08-20T21:42:25","request-id":"c5424acf-ded6-4b76-b3ad-97bfcb6ce824","client-request-id":"c5424acf-ded6-4b76-b3ad-97bfcb6ce824"}}}
Then I used Device Flow authenticatioin but it's asking for a "client_secret"
import msal
import requests
import time

CLIENT_ID = os.getenv("client_id")
TENANT_ID = os.getenv('tenant_id')
AUTHORITY = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{os.getenv('tenant_id')}"
SCOPE = ['Files.Read']

app = msal.PublicClientApplication(
    CLIENT_ID,
    authority=AUTHORITY
)

device_flow = app.initiate_device_flow(scopes=SCOPE)
if 'user_code' not in device_flow:
    raise ValueError("Failed to create device flow.")

print(device_flow['message'])

while True:
    result = app.acquire_token_by_device_flow(device_flow)
    
    if "access_token" in result:
        print("Access token acquired.")
        break
    elif result.get("error") == "authorization_pending":
        time.sleep(5)
    else:
        print(f"Failed to authenticate: {result.get('error_description')}")
        break

access_token = result.get('access_token')
if access_token:
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    
    graph_url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children'
    
    response = requests.get(graph_url, headers=headers)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        files = response.json()
        print("OneDrive Files:")
        for item in files.get('value', []):
            print(f"- {item['name']}")
    else:
        print(f"Error: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")
else:
    print("No access token obtained.")

"AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'.
